# Submit without refresh with 2 buttons

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello so I have 2 submit buttons with different names (btn1, btn2) in my html form and what I am trying to do is to submit to another page without refreshing page. So what I wanted to do is if I click btn1 submit it will do something and if I click btn2 it will do another thing. My code in the html page is this

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Percentage</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {

$.ajax({
url:'update.php',
data:$(this).serialize(),
type:'POST',
success:function(data){
console.log(data);
$("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
},
error:function(data){
$("#error").show().fadeOut(5000); //===Show Error Message====
}
});
e.preventDefault();
});
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" id="myForm">
    Input Amount: <input type="text" name="txt_amount" required placeholder="Input number"> <br /> <br />
     <span id="error" style="display:none; color:#F00">Some Error!Please Fill form Properly </span> <span id="success" style="display:none; color:#0C0">All the records are submitted!</span>
    <input type="submit" name="btn1"> <input type="submit" name="btn2"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code in my update.php page

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn1'])) {
 //insert query
} else if(isset($_POST['btn2'])) {
 //another insert query
}
?>
```

I actually got it working if I only have 1 submit button and no `if(isset())` thing in the update.php page. What can I do to use 2 submits and with issets in another page without refreshing the main page?

Comment: provide ids to your button and instead of submit change its type to button. then while click on button call different function on java script and server your purpose.

Comment: what is the purpose of second button if the first button already submits the form..?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, check console for data that is posted.

Comment: @MoidMohd each button performs different query.. for example I clicked button 1, it will perform addition in first column and subtraction in 2nd column in table, then if i clicked button 2 it will perform vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).serialize();
```

The above code statement doesn't include name of the submit button as a key value pair.

So, as people have suggested before me, you should use button instead of submit button. Something like this.

HTML and JS

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Percentage</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn1, #btn2').on('click',function(e) {
      var datastr = $(this).serialize() + "&button_id="+$(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url:'update.php',
            data:datastr,
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
            },
            error:function(data){
            $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000); //===Show Error Message====
            }
        });  
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" id="myForm" action="update.php">
    Input Amount: <input type="text" name="txt_amount" required placeholder="Input number"> <br /> <br />
     <span id="error" style="display:none; color:#F00">Some Error!Please Fill form Properly </span> <span id="success" style="display:none; color:#0C0">All the records are submitted!</span>
    <button id="btn1">Button1</button><button id="btn2">Button2</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

AND PHP would be:

```
<?php
if($_POST['button_id'] == 'btn1') {
 //do something
} else if($_POST['button_id'] == 'btn2') {
 //do something else;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello I got it working by changing your code var datastr = $(this).serialize() + "&button_id="+$(this).attr('id'); to var amount = $("#amount").val();
      var datastr = "txt_amount="+amount + "&button_id="+$(this).attr('id'); to get the txt_amount value also.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, may useful for you

try

```
  $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

OR

```
<button type="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on click event on the button and add the value attribute to the submit button, the value of the click button will be pased to the php file

```
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Percentage</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    url:'update.php',
    data:{'txt_amount':$('input[name="txt_amount"]').val(),'btn': $('input[type="submit"]').val()}
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
    },
    error:function(data){
    $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000); //===Show Error Message====
    }
    });
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" id="myForm">
        Input Amount: <input type="text" name="txt_amount" required placeholder="Input number"> <br /> <br />
         <span id="error" style="display:none; color:#F00">Some Error!Please Fill form Properly </span> <span id="success" style="display:none; color:#0C0">All the records are submitted!</span>
        <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="btn1"> <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="btn2"> 
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

php:

```
<?php
if($_POST['btn'] == 'btn1') {
 //do something
} else if($_POST['btn'] == 'btn2') {
 //do something else;
}
?>
```